# functionality of pci_set_dma_mask

Tags: c, pci

I am bit confused for pci_set_dma_mask. So can somebody explain me what exactly happens in below code.

```
#define DMA_64BIT_MASK DMA_BIT_MASK(64)
pci_set_dma_mask(dev, DMA_64BIT_MASK)
```

Regards
Rabinarayan

Comment: Assuming this is Linux kernel code, it tells the kernel that the PCI device supports DMA transfers to/from 64-bit physical addresses. You shouldn't set this mask unless the device actually supports it, and you may need to program the device's DMA registers or DMA descriptors to use a "dual address cycle". If supported, use of this option may speed up streaming DMA transfers to or from high memory by avoiding the use of bounce buffers.

Answer (score 4):

Basically **DMA_BIT_MASK(64)** is a macro that returns a 64bit address of '1's. 
ie. 
0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF

If **DMA_BIT_MASK(32)** is used, it would be 
0xFFFF FFFF

**pci_set_dma_mask(dev, DMA_64BIT_MASK)** is used to query the pcie device represented by dev : do you support 64-bit DMA? dev is provided when the standard kernel driver initialization routines are called.

From kernel documentation :

> It returns zero if your card can perform DMA properly on the machine
>   given the address mask you provided.  In general, the device struct of
>   your device is embedded in the bus-specific device struct of your
>   device.  For example, &pdev->dev is a pointer to the device struct of
>   a PCI device (pdev is a pointer to the PCI device struct of your
>   device).
>
> If it returns non-zero, your device cannot perform DMA properly on
>   this platform, and attempting to do so will result in undefined
>   behavior.  You must either use a different mask, or not use DMA.

Comment: Does it refer to DMA on soc side or external device side ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK know, this function returns 0 if the PCI device in parameter can perform the DMA on the supported PCI address. If it returns a non-zero then your device cannot perform DMA and the DMA translation (if used) is unpredictable.

Regardless of my answer, I don't think SO is a place for this kind of question as this is not really a problem that can have an absolutely correct "answer" or "solution"...